# Sublime Text 3 - Autocomplete de headers no diretorio

Tags: c, c++, linux, editor-de-texto, sublime-text-3

Após o insucesso na procura por um plugin no sublime text 3, venho pedir ajuda.

Preciso reconhecer as libs instaladas no sistema, para isso procuro um plugin capaz de fornecer um autocomple na hora do **#include** das headers *(ex. # include < exibir as opções de inclusão aqui>)*

Alguem conhece um plugin no sublime text 3 que forneça essa feature, como no Netbeans abaixo?

sistema operacional de uso do editor será o linux.

[image: Netbeans]

Answer (score 2):

## EasyClangComplete

Plugin autocomplete para linguagem  C++. Você encontrará o que deseja na configuração `include_dirs` Que irá buscar por bibliotecas externas como por exemplo `Boost`, `Ros`, `Eigen`, `OpenCV`, etc.

Onde `clang` deve procurar pelas bibliotecas:

```
    "include_dirs" : [
                        "/usr/include",
                        "$project_base_path/src",
                        "/workspace/$project_name/src",
                        "/usr/lib/clang/3.8/include"  // example for Ubuntu 16.04
],
```

Aqui você pode configurar.

Sem mais delongas acesse a página do plugin no [Github](https://github.com/niosus/EasyClangComplete) e faça o download para testar.

Comment: O plugin localiza para a compilação pelo proprio sublime, mais não faz o drop down das libs que tenho nesses diretorios.